# My Client Requests me to create a reusable template for scaled pricing

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to create the template for the tier pricing in configurable products so that the user doesn't have to create it again and again for each product?

[image]

The requirement is Instead of adding tier prices for a specific product the user can select a template in which the tier prices are already mentioned. I don't have any example though I haven't worked on or seen such functionality before.

Does magento support this functionality? If yes then please explain the logic I am also open to any sort of customization or using third party tools. IF not then please elaborate the reason.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, can you give us an example?

Comment: yes, The requirement is Instead of adding tier prices for a specific product the user can select a template in which the tier prices are already mentioned. I don't have any example though I haven't worked on or seen such functionality before.

Comment: I see what you mean now, you should perhaps edit your question. It seems a bit odd to me, not sure if an extension does it out there. Does the template selection also set the base price?

Comment: No, It doesn't set the Base Price. Also, I have edited the question :)

Comment: Now it all depends on how you create your products, are they created in an import or manually? Should the tier prices be created when the template is selected or on product save? Where/how would you store your templates?

Comment: Products will be created manually,  Tier pricing should be selected/implemented when the product is saved, so that it will visible on front-end,  I am not sure where to save the templates :(

Comment: This is gonna be tricky.

Comment: any idea/logic how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really have time to post detailed code, but I'll go over what you could do (with the semi-clean solution, the real solution being quite complicated).

- Create a new attribute to begin with, make it a dropdown list with values being your "templates" names/IDs.
- Store your tiers in a custom table.
- Create an Observer and watch the event `catalog_product_save_after` .
- In your event function:

  - query your custom table to gather tier prices given the value of your dropdown attribute.
  - add the tiers to the product you caught in the event.
  - save the product.

This should hopefully set your tiers accordingly. Be careful if you have multiple stores because the tiers can be set a different levels. Also beware of the fact that if you decide to change your tiers in your custom table, then you'll have to re-save the products depending on said tiers because the tiers won't change automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I will work on it and let you know the outcome, hopefully it will solve the problem. :)

Comment: Thank you So much for the Sound Logic, After much of coding it is working now, Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Julien Lachal for great Answer, I going to explain it with Code.

1. As described by @Julien

   > Create a new attribute to begin with, make it a dropdown list with
   >   values being your "templates" names/IDs.
   >   I created an attribute with code tier_custom having dropdown options.
2. In your custom module config.xml file Use the observer by writing below Code.

   ```
     <events>
       <catalog_product_save_before>
           <observers>
               <namespace_module_model_observer>
                   <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                   <method>detectProductChanges</method>
               </namespace_module_model_observer>
           </observers>
       </catalog_product_save_before>
     </events>
   ```
3. And create a file with name observer.php in Model directory of your custom module.

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer{
    public function detectProductChanges($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($product->hasDataChanges()) {
            // print_r($product->getTierCustom()); die;
            if($product->getTierCustom()){
                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
                    $tiername = $product->getAttributeText("tier_custom");
                    $query = $readConnection->query("SELECT price_qty,price,website_id,cust_group FROM tier_price_update WHERE name='$tiername'");
                    $resultnamer = $query->fetchAll();
                //Now we set the tier price and save the product
                $product->setTierPrice($resultnamer);
                $product->setTierCustom();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your event function:
query your custom table to gather tier prices given the value of your dropdown attribute.
add the tiers to the product you caught in the event.
save the product.

Don't forget to create the table with name - 'tier_price_update'.